# grails parent service dependency not injected

Tags: grails

I am finding that when we have inheritance within the services in grails app the injection is not taking place correctly in the parent class.
Ex: ParentService->ChildService
ParentService has property XXX that needs to be injected.

As long as property was in ChildService there were no issues...

I read that by default spring does not autowire the parent also, so do I need to redeclare each of the services in resources.groovy and mention parent="name of Parent Service Class" ?

Is there no annotation to do the same?